# Finding an xml node by its name rather than by its index

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

How do I find an xml node by its name and get its value between the tags?

I'm doing that the following way:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(some_xml), "utf-8"))
self.a1 = dom.childNodes[0].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue
self.a2 = dom.childNodes[0].childNodes[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

I want to do that using the name of the tag instead of using its index in an array `childNodes`. How?

**update**:

```
<ReconnectResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1"> 
  <ErrorMessage /> 
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode> 
  <ServerTime>aaa</ServerTime> 
  <OAuthToken>bbb</OAuthToken> 
  <OAuthTokenSecret>ccc</OAuthTokenSecret> 
</ReconnectResponse>
```

and the code:

```
dom.getElementsByTagName("ServerTime") # => []
```

**update2**

```
dom.toxml()
u'<?xml version="1.0" ?><ns0:ReconnectResponse xmlns:ns0="http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1">\n  <ns0:ErrorMessage/>\n  <ns0:ErrorCode>0</ns0:ErrorCode>\n  <ns0:ServerTime>aaa</ns0:ServerTime>\n  <ns0:OAuthToken>bbb</ns0:OAuthToken>\n  <ns0:OAuthTokenSecret>ccc</ns0:OAuthTokenSecret>\n</ns0:ReconnectResponse>'
```

but how I get the value? I tried this:

```
dom.getElementsByTagName("ns0:OAuthToken")
[<DOM Element: ns0:OAuthToken at 0x10635a878>]
(Pdb) dom.getElementsByTagName("ns0:OAuthToken")[0]
<DOM Element: ns0:OAuthToken at 0x10635a878>
(Pdb) dom.getElementsByTagName("ns0:OAuthToken")[0].nodeValue
(Pdb) dom.getElementsByTagName("ns0:OAuthToken")[0].toxml()
u'<ns0:OAuthToken>aaaaaa</ns0:OAuthToken>'
```

Comment: Usually xpath is pretty standard approach. Do you explicitly want `minidom`? or can you use `lxml`?

Comment: It looks like you're using elementtree -- can't you just `root.find(tagname)`?

Comment: @stanleyxu2005, minidom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [getElementsByTagNameNS](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.getElementsByTagNameNS), because you don't have a tag named `ServerTime`, you have one named `{http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1}ServerTime` (where `{http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1}` indicates the default namespace.)

```
getElementsByTagNameNS("http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1", "ServerTime")
```

This namespace is implicitly added to every tag in your XML body, due to the last property of the document element:

```
<ReconnectResponse ... xmlns="http://ccc.aaa.bbb/api/v1">
```

Comment: I can confirm that it works without namespace as well.

Comment: It may depend on your version of Python/lxml/ET/minidom, because it does NOT work without the namespace for me. Without using `dom.getElementsByTagNameNS()`, I get an empty list, just like OP. See [this eval.in](https://eval.in/209271) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

> Usually using `lxml` and xpath is a common approach in Python.

As you want to use `minidom` explicitly, you can use the following method to get all HTML elements of a particular tag.

```
matches = dom.getElementsByTagName("foo")
for e in matches:
    print(e.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Comment: actually, dom.getElementsByTagName("my_tag") always returns [] for some reason.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Better paste your xml content in your question.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp I can get 'aaa' as result expectedly.